# $\frac{2}{3}^{\text{th}}$ roots of $4 + 4\sqrt{3}i$

Tags: complex-numbers

A textbook, in a section about roots of unity, poses the problem

> Find the values of
> $$ \left( 4\sqrt{3} + 4i \right)^{\frac{2}{3}} $$

The answer key says

> $$ w \in \left\{ 4e^{-100^\circ i}, \quad 4e^{20^\circ i}, \quad 4e^{140^\circ i} \right\} $$

and I know exactly how this was obtained, but the problem is if I let $w = 4e^{140^\circ i}$, for example, I get
$$
w^\frac{3}{2} = 8e^{210^\circ i} \neq 4\sqrt{3} + 4i = 8e^{30^\circ i}
$$

I think that the problem is $ \left( 4\sqrt{3} + 4i \right)^{\frac{2}{3}} $ is intended by the author to mean the solutions to the equation
$$
w^{\frac{3}{2}} = 4\sqrt{3} + 4i
$$
in which case, when we square both sides in order to solve
$$
w^3 = (4\sqrt{3} + 4i)^2
$$
we pick up some false solutions.

My question is, are the answers in the book incorrect, or do I misunderstand the meaning of $z^{\frac{a}{b}}$, or is the whole concept of $\frac{a}{b}^{\text{th}}$ roots of a complex number just badly defined?

Comment: I think it usually means the $b$th roots of $z^a$

Comment: Looks like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%284%2B4*sqrt%283%29*i%29%5E%282%2F3%29) produces different values.

Comment: I there should be some $\pi$-s around there which you omitted.

Comment: You have the leter $i$ missing here and there.

Comment: Thanks for noticing some typos! I think I've fixed them now. The arguments are in degrees (sorry I should have said that at the beginning).

Comment: You cannot do $(z^a)^b$ and expect to get $z^{ab}$.  You will need to use the definition for $z^a$ with $a=3/2$ to get your answer.

Comment: .....In which case, when we square both sides in order to solve
$$
w^3 = (4 + 4\sqrt{3}i)^2$$ ...and we pick up false solutions...
The question really then becomes, what is your (and the author's) INTEPRETATION of $
w^{\frac{3}{2}} = 4 + 4\sqrt{3}i
$? Because that becomes ambiguous.

Comment: I agree the answer key is wrong.  The argument for $4+4\sqrt{3}i$ is $60^\circ$, so we need $2/3$ of that, $40^\circ$. for one of the solutions.

Comment: Oh no I messed up the real and imaginary parts - thanks @GEdgar. I think this doesn't change the comments and answer so far since I think everyone has taken it at face value so far that the argument is $30^{\circ}$. I'm making the edit now.

Comment: So the answer key is now correct.  You are also correct: we may get extra solutions if we square both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the given solutions, $w^{3/2}$ is one of $$8e^{-150°i},8e^{30°i},8e^{210°i},$$ where the arguments differ by $180°$. These numbers are

$$\pm(4\sqrt{3}+4i).$$

Comment: No, $\cos(30^\circ)=\sqrt3/3$ and $\sin(30^\circ)=1/2$ so $8e^{30^\circ i} = 4\sqrt{3}+4i$.

Comment: It was my mistake - I mixed up Re and Im. I've made the edit and I'l suggest the edit in this answer.

Comment: Right - I think I'm getting it. By analogy with $x^2 = 4$ and $x = 4^{\frac{1}{2}},$ when we think about $w^{\frac{b}{a}} = z$ and $w = z^{\frac{a}{b}}$ we need to clear about what we really mean when writing the indices.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question with a bit more explanation including what I learned from this example.

In general
$$
\left( z^{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^{\frac{b}{a}}
$$
can be broken down into a few steps.
$$
z^{\frac{a}{b}}
$$
is taken to mean the set of $b^{\text{th}}$ roots of $z^{a}$, and so
$$
\left( z^{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^{\frac{b}{a}}
$$
means the set of $a^{\text{th}}$ roots of
$$
\left( z^{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^{b}
$$
Now, any of the $b^{\text{th}}$ roots of $z^{a}$ to the power $b$ do indeed give $z^{a}$, so we can write
$$
\left( z^{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^{b} = z^{a}
$$
which is a slight abuse of notation, given that $z^{\frac{a}{b}}$ is interpreted as a set, but we'll let that go for now. So, finally we have
$$
\left( z^{\frac{a}{b}} \right)^{\frac{b}{a}} = (z^{a})^{\frac{1}{a}}
$$
which are the $a^{\text{th}}$ roots of $z^{a},$ and we should not be surprised that these are not all $z$ any more than the $3^{\text{rd}}$ roots of $2^{3}$ are not all $2.$

For our specific example,
$$
\left((4\sqrt{3} + 4i)^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}
= \left((4\sqrt{3} + 4i)^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$
which is the set of square roots of $(4\sqrt{3} + 4i)^{2}$, i.e.
$$
\pm (4\sqrt{3} + 4i)
$$

Comment: @Yves Daoust I took some time to try to really understand your answer and I've fleshed it out for myself - does this make sense? Thank you for your help!